# Notification in Swift returning UserInfo in dictionary

Tags: swift, notifications, ios8, xcode6

I have a Notification that returns a dictionary, much like in objective-c, but I am not getting the results I expect.

Here is the method that is posting the Notification.  It's actually returning the results (date) of date picker.

```
@IBAction func dateOfBirthAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("Date: \(dateOfBirthPicker.date)")

    var selectedDateDictionary = [dateOfBirthPicker.date, "dateOfBirth"]

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dateOfBirth", object: nil, userInfo: [NSObject():selectedDateDictionary])

}
```

Here is the notification observer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dateOfBirth:", name: "dateOfBirth", object: nil)

}

func dateOfBirth(notification: NSNotification) {

    println("userInfo: \(notification.userInfo)")

    let returnedDateOfBirth = notification.userInfo!["dateOfBirth"] as NSString
    println("returnedDateOfBirth: \(returnedDateOfBirth)")

    playerInformationDateOfBirthLabel.text  = returnedDateOfBirth
}
```

I'm getting the following error on the line line `let returnedDateOfBirth:String = notification.userInfo["dateOfBirth"]`

```
userInfo: Optional([<NSObject: 0x7fb15a44a880>: <_TtCSs23_ContiguousArrayStorage00007FB15A4D4380 0x7fb15a4206a0>(
2014-09-18 12:07:07 +0000,
dateOfBirth
)
])
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

### FULL SOLUTION

```
@IBAction func dateOfBirthAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var selectedDateDictionary = ["birthDate" : dateOfBirthPicker.date]

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("foundABirthDate", object: nil, userInfo:selectedDateDictionary)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dateOfBirth:", name: "foundABirthDate", object: nil)

}

func dateOfBirth(notification: NSNotification) {

    let playerBirthDate = notification.userInfo!["birthDate"] as NSDate

    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    //Specifies a long style, typically with full text, such as “November 23, 1937”.
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle

    let dateConvertedToString: String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(playerBirthDate)

    playerInformationDateOfBirthLabel.text  = dateConvertedToString
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `userInfo` dictionary is wrong.

You have:

```
[NSObject():selectedDateDictionary]
```

Try setting `userInfo` to `userInfo: selectedDateDictionary` like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dateOfBirth", object: nil, userInfo: selectedDateDictionary)
```

The error is telling you that you are expecting a `String` because of `returnedDateOfBirth:String` but you return `[NSObject():selectedDateDictionary]`

Comment: Your suggestion (as I originally did it) gives an error:  Extra argument 'userInfo' in call

Comment: What's the error? Also, i just noticed that your `selectedDateDictionary` isn't instantiated correctly. If you want a dictionary you need to do `var selectedDateDictionary = ["dateOfBirth": dateOfBirthPicker.date]`

Comment: Great thanks, that fixed the problem with the dictionary and postNotificationName.  However, now I'm getting a EXC_BREAKPOINT on the `let returnedDateOfBirth = notification.userInfo!["dateOfBirth"] as NSString` line

Comment: @PaulS. use object.    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dateOfBirth", object: pageDict, userInfo: nil)

Comment: Now that that 1st error is gone what does `println("userInfo: \(notification.userInfo)")` show you?

Comment: `userInfo: Optional([dateOfBirth: 2014-09-17 12:27:47 +0000])`

Comment: Break it into 2 lines and check again. What does `let returnedDateOfBirth = notification.userInfo` print out? Remove the `!["dateOfBirth"] as NSString` and print out `returnedDateOfBirth`. Then inspect `returnedDateOfBirth`. Basically, you should keep breaking things down until you identify the source of the issue.

Comment: Any luck with the issue?

Comment: `returnedDateOfBirth: Optional([dateOfBirth: 2014-09-18 12:54:47 +0000])`

Comment: That's good. So it matches `userInfo` as expected. Now try printing `returnedDateOfBirth["dateOfBirth"]`. Confirm you still have the same error.

Comment: Seems like we are back where we started.  You can't println the dictionary key, so I have to do this `let sample = returnedDateOfBirth!["dateOfBirth"] as NSString
        println("\(sample)")`  Once again it crashes with a EXC_BREAKPOINT

Comment: Instead of `dateOfBirthPicker.date` for the value try "test string" when you create the dictionary. What happens? Are you sure that `dateOfBirthPicker.date` is actually an `NSString`?

Comment: `dateOfBirthPicker.date` is an NSdate.  So the following fixes my problem: `let sample = returnedDateOfBirth!["birthDate"] as NSDate`  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help! Happy you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Try it
Only dictionary can pass to userInfo

```
        var pageDict: Dictionary<String,String>! = [
            "dateOfBirth": "11/5/1987date",
        ]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dateOfBirth", object: nil, userInfo: pageDict)
```

or

```
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dateOfBirth", object: pageDist, userInfo: nil)
```