# Call Function in a ViewController from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I call a function of a `ViewController` from a custom tableview cell of a `UITableView` in that `ViewController` (using SWIFT)?

Comment: use `protocol-delegate` or keep a weak reference of the ViewController instance.

Comment: can you please elaborate when do you want to call the function or show some code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are few ways you can do that

1. [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) (create a protocol delegate uitableViewcell) set view controller as delegate of `UITabelVeiwCell` and then from cell call `self.delegate.whatEverDeelgate()`
2. Post notification from the cell and register observer for that notification inside view controller view `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "nameOfSelector", name: "Name Of Notification", object: nil)` and then from tableView cell postNotification, but make sure you want to removeObserver as well, visit this [link](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) for more detail
3. Keep a weakReference of viewController inside UITableViewCell, means create a property `@weak var viewController:YourViewcontroller` and use this to call method on view controller (Not recommended)
4. Add observer on a key path aka [KVO](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) (this will call a method in view controller when a property changes its value) may be not necessary for your scenario

Comment: thanks so much but can please give me example of Delegation  in this case cell start trigger and the parent view controller run a function

Answer (score 5):

Post a notification from your cell:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notificationName", object: nil)
```

Then listen out for it in your viewController:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "functionToCall", name: "notificationName", object: nil)
```

Make sure you define the new function in your viewController:

```
func functionToCall() {
    //This function will be called when you post the notification
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass a parameter this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25933545/3641111 Check out where it says full solution in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `protocol` in your `UIableViewCell` class.

Make your `ViewController` delegate of this protocol.

On some action from your cell, call this delegate method.